# How could I save in th same .mat file without deleting the contenu of the file?

Tags: octave

I need to save in the same'file.mat' three matrix M1,M2,M3; with a very test i get one of those matrix,  after all tests, each matrix needs to be saved in the same file.

```
function [M1,M2,M3]= atlet(Numtest)
 if (Numtest==1)
  %instruction
elseif (Numtest==2)
 %instruction
elseif (Numtest==3)
 %instruction
endif
save ('alter_test.mat','M1','M2','M3')

endfunction
```

every time I have just one matrix, however i need to save all of them in alter_test.mat without deleting anyone.
for example when I pass this command:

```
[M1,M2,M3]= atlet(1)
```

I got in alter_test.mat the matrix M1
when I pass this command then:

```
[M1,M2,M3]= atlet(2)
```

I got in alter_test.mat the matrix M2 and M1 is deleted.
However i need to have both of them M1 and M2.
I would  be very  gratful If you could help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to append to the .mat file , however -append will refresh your indices. you could define a two by two matrix in this case and increase the row every time the .mat file is being called in a loop, this way for example your M1 will be an array of M1 results documented earlier.
to do so first:

```
1.load the .mat file: load('alter_tst.mat','M1','M2','M3');
2.append your new M1-M3 to the previous ones named MT1, MT2,MT3: M1=[M1;MT1];
3.save('alter_tst.mat','M1','M2','M3','-append');
```

save(..., 'append')To append to the previous save, then later you can bring the previous save to the workspace and append the new matrix to the old matrix thus creating a 2 X 3 matrix and later n x 3 matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.